# How to determine if HTML element is descendant of other. The child may not be immediate child

Tags: javascript

I am capturing `keydown` event for my document. This event can be fired from anywhere in the document. The document is made up of several `divs`. I want to determine if the HTML element that fired `keydown` event is descendant of particular `div`. Lets say I have the documnet which looks like this:

```
<div class="div1">...</div>
<div class="div2">
    <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" id="txt1"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div3">...</div>
```

If `txt1` fires keydown event I need to determine if it is descendant of `div2`. `txt1` could be immediate child or grand-child or so on. Please let me know how can we do it?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains

Comment: @CBroe: The element need not always be immediate child. It could be  child of child or child of child of child and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.matches` to see if an element matches a particular selector:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input')
  .forEach((input) => {
    input.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if (e.target.matches('.div2 input')) console.log('matches');
      else console.log("doesn't match");
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="div2">
  <div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="txt1" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="txt2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Node.parentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement) and [ParentNode.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children) properties provided by Javascript. In this way, you can determine if the parent element is div1 or div2.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use jquery you can do this

```
$('inputValue').keydown(function(){
    if($(this).closest('your class name , or div')){
    console.log('inside');
  }

});
```

if it returns true then it means your element is inside that particular div value otherwise its not